# C++ char Arrays comparing to arrays and assigning individual values;

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to assign the elements from an array to another but testing if they are equal I want to assign that element to a specific array if they are not I want to assign that element to another different array, somehow I cannot copy those particular elements after testing if they are equal or not

[image]

```
   int QUESTIONS=20;
    // the data inside the arrays of  chr Example="A","B";
    char correctAnswers[QUESTIONS];
    char studentAnswers[QUESTIONS];
    void findExamResult(char[],char[],int);
    
    
    findExamResult(correctAnswers,studentAnswers,QUESTIONS);call back
    
    void findExamResult(char rightAns [],char studentAns[],int SIZE)
    {
        char findExamResult(char rightAns [],char studentAns[],int SIZE)
{
      //the SIZE is the same for both arrays which is 20;
    char badAns[SIZE];
    char goodAns[SIZE];
/*comparing to arrays and attending to assign one element to another depending
  of the test;*/

    for(int index=0;index<SIZE;index++)
    {
        if(rightAns[index]!=studentAns[index])
        {
           badAns[index]=studentAns[index];
        }
        else
        {
            goodAns[index]=rightAns[index];

        }

    }

     //Loop to Display
        for(int index=0;index<SIZE;index++)
    {
        cout<<badAns[index]<<"\n";
        cout<<goodAns[index]<<"\n";
    }

}
```

The output is set random char that have nothing to with what attend.

Comment: For those indexes where `rightAns[index] == studentAns[index]` the `badAns[index]` are left undetermined (because you haven't assigned any value to them), thus producing random characters.

Comment: how and comparing them if one of them is not equal that value is assigned to  badAns array like you say is random values what is display can you explain ho to achieve this

Comment: `if(rightAns[index]!=studentAns[index])` -- What do you do if `if(rightAns[index] == studentAns[index])`?  All of that should have been part of your design when you wrote the program.  We really can't answer you as to what to do -- you need to go back to your teacher, or re-read the assignment, etc. to determine what is done when that condition is met.

Comment: also, there's no need to assign value to an array aslong you have the SIZE of the array you can pass a value to it so far I know?

Comment: what you do is :  else add the goodAns[index] =rightAns[inxdex] that is how i havet it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your final for loop, badAns[] only populates indices where answers don't match. The other indices are left blank and, thus, a random char takes their place when you try and print them.

Perhaps try and add an else statement in the for loop so if the answers DO match, there is some char that signifies this when you print it (i.e. '+' could signify that the answers did match).

If you don't want the matched answers to print at all, use a std::vector. Vectors can be resized at runtime using `myVector.push_back(myElement)`, so you don't need to declare a fixed size and you can just push_back the wrong answers.

**EDIT**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const int QUESTIONS = 20;

void findExamResult(char rightAns [],char studentAns[],int SIZE)
{
    char badAns[SIZE];

    for(int index=0;index<SIZE;index++)
    {
        if(rightAns[index]!=studentAns[index])
        {
            badAns[index]=studentAns[index];
        } else {
            badAns[index] = '+';
        }

    }


    //Loop to Display
    for(int index=0;index<SIZE;index++)
    {
        cout<<badAns[index]<<"\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    char correctAnswers[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'};
    char studentAnswers[] = {'b' , 'a', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'b' , 'a', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'b' , 'a', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'b' , 'a', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'b' , 'a', 'c', 'd', 'f'};
    findExamResult(correctAnswers,studentAnswers,QUESTIONS);
}
```

Comment: I tried an else statement with the one it matches and doesn't work  neither

Comment: Can you update the question with your else statement?

Comment: I cannot use vectors

Comment: Can you please add your else statement so we can see what went wrong there?

Comment: I've updated my answer with code that works for me, if I'm understanding what you need correctly. Make sure to try and understand what's going on and write the code yourself.

Comment: It doesn't look like you've added an else statement at all... Re-read my answer and the code I posted please.

Comment: wuao it worked i need to understand this why it worked your way and using my values im it works perfectly

Comment: i know what is happening but i dont see the problem itself in doing it please check on top where i put my else statement i assign gooAns[index]=rightAns[index]

Comment: Your goodAns array is not the same as your badAns array. In your else statement, you are adding values to your goodAns array, NOT your badAns array. In your for loop, you are ONLY outputting your badAns array, which still has undeclared values at those indices. Your else statement changed the wrong array.

Comment: i see but how could i separate them from each other so it can be displayed

Comment: You would need to add placeholder values to your arrays. So if an answer is correct, set goodAns[index] to the answer and set the badAns[index] to a placeholder, let's say '+'. Then, while looping through your badAns array, if badAns[i] == '+', we can cout goodAns[i], otherwise we would cout badAns[i].

Comment: I just want to then be separated into different arrays so I can do something with them

Comment: but I don't see how that could be achieved I read the book two times and it doesn't explain how to separate the elements  and pass them to an array

Comment: I see. Okay, so you would need to keep a counter for each array to represent the number of populated elements.

Comment: Can you show me I Literally been in this part for about 8 hours of the program, not JOKING I read the book i google nothing appears for example like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
int QUESTIONS=20;
    // the data inside the arrays of  chr Example="A","B";
    char correctAnswers[QUESTIONS];
    char studentAnswers[QUESTIONS];
    void findExamResult(char[],char[],int);




    void findExamResult(char rightAns [],char studentAns[],int SIZE)
    {

    char badAns[SIZE];
    char goodAns[SIZE];

    for(int index=0;index<SIZE;index++)
    {
        if(rightAns[index]!=studentAns[index])
        {
           badAns[index]=studentAns[index];
           goodAns[index] = " ";
        }
        else
        {
            badAns[index] = " ";
            goodAns[index]=rightAns[index];

        }

    }

for(int index=0;index<SIZE;index++)
    {
        cout<<badAns[index]<<"\n";
    }
}
```

so When answer got match then goodAns score one but badAns score nothing on that index. So give some character on not matching like null or just empty string. Visa-Versa

Comment: it separates the wrong answers but doesn't do anything with the good ones;

Comment: I thought you could od this because of parallel arrays but is not possible so far a tried thanks for the help anyway

Answer (score 0):

**This is how you actually test an array of char them use a counter to storage the numbers of time that we have not equal value, then use a loop to display the value in the array depending if one is true or false **

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
/*
Program Description:
"The Program must read the files CorrectAnswer
 and StudentAnswer, check and display the number of correct
 answers and miss questions for the student.
 Give a percentage and Final score if pass or Not."

 */
using namespace std;
//Functions Prototype;
char readRightAns(char [],int,ifstream&);
char readStudeAns(char [],int,ifstream&);
char showAns( const char[],const char [],int);
int findExamResult(char [],char[],int);
void displayQuestions(char[],char[],int,int);



int main()
{

   //notice  you need 20 char for "SIZE"  im reading from a file to test this code;

    /*notice i use two different names for the ifstream,
      to open both file at the same time;*/
    ifstream inData;
    ifstream inData_2;
    int QUESTIONS=20;
    int missed;
    char correctAnswers[QUESTIONS];
    char studentAnswers[QUESTIONS];



    //Description of the Program;
    cout<<"//Description of the Program: \n";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"============================================================"<<endl;
    cout<<"Hey there,this program attend to read the answers\n"
          "from the file correctAnswer and the StudentsAnswers\n"
          "evaluated them and display the miss question and\n"
          "correct answers for each one the 20 questions,\n"
          "and display a percentage base in the total correct answer\n"
          "to determine if the student pass successfully the Exam or Not\n"
          <<endl;
    cout<<"============================================================"<<endl;
    //======Opening the Files=========;
    inData.open("CorrectAnswers.txt");
    inData_2.open("studentAnswers.txt");
    //================================
    //validating if Read File;
    if(inData&&inData_2)
    {
        //Call functions to Read Data from files
        readRightAns(correctAnswers,QUESTIONS,inData);
        readStudeAns(studentAnswers,QUESTIONS,inData_2);
        cout<<left <<setw(10)<<"Total Questions";
        cout<<right<<setw(30)<<"These are Correct Answers";
        cout<<right<<setw(30)<<"These are student Answers";
        cout<<"\n" <<endl;
        //Calling Function showAns to display All Answers;
        showAns(correctAnswers,studentAnswers,QUESTIONS);

        cout<<"==========================================================\n";
        //Assigning total of missed question to "missed";
        missed=findExamResult(correctAnswers,studentAnswers,QUESTIONS);
        displayQuestions(correctAnswers,studentAnswers,QUESTIONS,missed);


    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"File not Open"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }

return 0;
}

//=======Functions Definitions=========;
/*This Function read the file CorrectAnswer and Store the value,
  in the correctAnswers Array;*/
char readRightAns(char rightAns[],int SIZE,ifstream&inData)
{
    for(int index=0;index<SIZE;index++)
    {
      inData>>rightAns[index];
    }
    inData.close();
}
/*This Function read the file StudentAnswer and Store the value,
  in the studentAnswers Array;*/
char readStudeAns(char studentAns[],int SIZE,ifstream&inData_2)
{
    for(int index=0;index<SIZE;index++)
    {
      inData_2>>studentAns[index];
    }
    inData_2.close();
}
//this function attend to Display answers;
char showAns(const char rightAns[],const char studentAns[],int SIZE)
{
    int cols=1;//temporal variable
    for(int i=0;i<cols;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<SIZE;j++)
        {
            cout<<left<<setw(5)<<"Question #"<<setw(5)<< j+1<<
            setw(5)<<right<<setw(10)<<rightAns[j]<<right<<
            setw(28)<<studentAns[j]<<endl;
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
//This function Finds the outcome of the Exam;
int findExamResult(char rightAns [],char studentAns[],int SIZE)
{
    int counter=0;
    for(int index=0;index<SIZE;index++)
    {
        if(rightAns[index]!=studentAns[index])
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
//display the missed Questions
void displayQuestions(char rightAns[],char studentAns[],int SIZE,int missed)
{

    cout<<setw(10)<<"Missed Questions are:"<<setw(29)<<"Correct Answers are:"<<endl;
    cout<<"\n";
    for(int i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        if(rightAns[i]!=studentAns[i])
        {
          cout<<left<<"Missed #"<<setw(5)<< i+1<<setw(17)<<studentAns[i]<<
              "Correct #"<<setw(5)<<i+1<<setw(40)<<rightAns[i]<<" \n";
        }
    }
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"This total of Questions Missed are "<<missed<<endl;
}
```